# whats makes JIRA better than Redmine

Tags: jira, redmine

I understood that for managing bugs a startups used redmine because it is free and open source, and a company that is not startup used JIRA (most of them)(in payment).

why do these companies prefers JIRA above Redmine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that this question might be better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

A quick internet search yields:

```
https://de.atlassian.com/software/jira/comparison/jira-vs-redmine
http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/18986?r=33542 
https://www.quora.com/How-does-Redmine-compare-to-JIRA?share=1
http://project-management.softwareinsider.com/saved_compare/JIRA-vs-Redmine
```

So the customizable visual workflow and easy setup might be main reasons.